# Матрица - упорядочивание элементов, создание вектора из матрицы

Tags: массивы, матрицы, вектор, c++, сортировка

Разработать алгоритм и программу на языке С++ решения следующих взаимосвязанных задач:

- 1) рассчитать элементы квадратной матрицы `A = (aij ), i,j = 0,1,2,...,n-1` по заданной формуле;
- 2) сформировать из матрицы A элементы вектора `X = (xi), i = 0,1,2,...,n-1` по заданному правилу;
- 3) провести заданное упорядочение элементов матрицы А или вектора Х.
- 1) `a[i,j]=(4,5-i)^j/1`
- 2) хi – скалярное произведение второго столбца на i-ю строку;
- 3) упорядочить элементы второй строки матрицы А по возрастанию абсолютных значений;

Сделал первое и второе(не совсем работает). Помогите со вторым и третьим пунктом. Заранее спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cout << "Enter size of matrix A:" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Creating matrix A:" << endl;
    // Создаётся матрица A
    double **A = new double* [N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++) A[i] = new double [N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++)
        {
            A[i][j] = pow(4.5-i,j);
            cout << setw(10) << A[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    int num;
    cout << "Enter str number of matrix A:" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << "Creating array X:" << endl;
    // Создаётся вектор X
    double *X = new double [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++)
        {
            X[i]=A[num][j]*A[i][1];
        }
        cout << setw(10) << X[i];
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
 // Освобождение памяти
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) delete [] A[i];
    delete [] A;
    delete [] X;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) Вам не нужно спрашивать индекс `num`. Скалярное произведение - это сумма поэлементных произведений, а в этом цикле Вы вычисляете просто поэлементное произведение:

```
for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++)
{
    X[i]=A[num][j]*A[i][1];
}
```

Надо так:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) // перебираем строки
  {
      X[i] = 0;
      for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++) // этот индекс перебирает i-ю строку
                                  // и элементы второго столбца
      {
          X[i] += A[i][j]  // элемент i-й строки
                  * A[j][1]; // элемент второго столбца
      }
      cout << setw(10) << X[i];
  }
```

3) В 3ем пункте нужно отсортировать массив 'A[1][0] .. A[1][N-1]'.

Думаю, Вы справитесь. `std::sort` или `qsort` Вам в помощь.